# Culmative vs Exclusive Rights

Tags: contract-law, rental-property, residential-lease

Fellow Lawmen,

I have come across this clause in a Lease agreement & I cannot find definitions anywhere on the internet:

“The rights of the parties under this Lease are **cumulative**, and shall not be construed as **exclusive** unless otherwise required by law.”

What does this mean. Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this mean

The Black's Law Dictionary defines "*exclusive right*" as "*one which only the grantee thereof can exercise, and from which all others are prohibited or shut out*".

The clause you reproduce provides that the rights are not exclusive. This means that a party/obligee/grantee may subrogate (that is, transfer to someone else) his right, and the obligor or counterparty to that contract does not have the defense that "*only the obligee has standing or entitlement to enforce that right*".

*Cumulative right* seemingly relates to *cumulative remedy*, which the aforementioned dictionary defines as "*a remedy created by statute in addition to one which still remains in force*". This means that a party's exercise of one of his rights does not preclude the exercise of his other rights.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and efforts sir.

Comment: Exclusive rights can be subrogated by the holder - they just can’t be offered to anyone else by the grantor. A publisher given exclusive rights in a region can sell those rights to other publishers in countries within those regions. The person who sold them can’t sell them to another publisher though.